# How to publish binary Protobuf to Google Cloud Pub/Sub with gcloud CLI tool?

Tags: command-line, protocol-buffers, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

It is possible to publish messages to Google Cloud Pub/Sub on (Unix/MacOS) command line with [gcloud pubsub topics publish](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/topics/publish), at least strings.

Is there a way to publish binary Protobuf? The command seems to take the data as a command line argument (e.g. `--message="My message"`), but I haven't found a way to pass binary Protobuf content.

Comment: Does this [article1](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) and [article2](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-proto-messages) by Google help you to solve your problem?

Comment: Not totally. I'm able to publish to Pub/Sub with various languages but was interested if there would be a way to do that with gcloud CLI. I didn't find help for that from the links.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is not a way to publish binary protobuf in gcloud.
I would recommend using the Pub/Sub python client library's quickstart as the quickest set-up to publish messages: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library